# on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the following statement in MySQL:

```
  INSERT IGNORE INTO shop_item_details (shop_id,product_id,product_name,Product_model,Product_category,Product_details,price) 
VALUES (1, NULL, 'camera', 'sony','', 'hd', '5000') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE (shop_id='1',product_id='',product_name='camera', Product_model='sony',Product_category='', Product_details='hd',price='5000')
```

But it produces an error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(shop_id='1',product_id='',product_name='camera', Product_model='sony',Product_c' at line 1

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Community Wiki answer originally based on notes by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9) and [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) suggested in the comments on the question.*</sup>

The immediate issue is the parentheses around the `UPDATE` set list: they should not be there [according to the syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html). That is what the error message is about.

Once you have fixed that one, there are other issues with your `INSERT` statement.

- The `IGNORE` keyword just does not make sense when used together with `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. You either perform an update when a duplicate key is encountered, or you ignore the duplicate key entry completely, and it looks as though you want the former – therefore, lose the `IGNORE` keyword.
- Setting *`product_id`* to `''` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause is not consistent with setting it to `NULL` in the `VALUES` clause: an empty string (`''`) is not the same as a null. Judging from the column name, you probably want to have `NULL` specified in both places.
- Similarly, seeting *`id`* to `'1'` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause is not consistent with setting it to `1` in the `VALUES` clause: the string (`'1'`) is not the same as the number (`1`). This will probably not be an issue as the string will be converted to a number but it doesn't hurt to be explicit and very careful with the types of your column and values you pass to them.
- While this is not exactly a problem, you don't have to specify the same values twice (in `VALUES` and in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clauses). You can specify them once and use them in two places, using the `VALUES()` function, like this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO shop_item_details 
    (shop_id, product_id, product_name, Product_model, 
     Product_category, Product_details, price) 
  VALUES 
    (1, NULL, 'camera', 'sony', '', 'hd', '5000') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    shop_id          = VALUES(shop_id), 
    product_id       = VALUES(product_id), 
    product_name     = VALUES(product_name), 
    Product_model    = VALUES(Product_model), 
    Product_category = VALUES(Product_category), 
    Product_details  = VALUES(Product_details), 
    price            = VALUES(price) ;
  ```

  Please note that the above is just an example. Since you are updating the same set of columns as those you are inserting into, setting *each* of them using the `column = VALUES(column)` pattern is slightly redundant. The columns that define the unique (or primary) key being violated (you have not specified which columns they are in your case - perhaps *`shop_id`* and *`product_id`*? Or *`shop_id`* and *`product_name`* and *`product_model`*?) can be safely removed from the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.